# What does "2007 - date" mean?

Tags: meaning

I saw an example of someone's résumé through a Google search, in the 'work experience' section she wrote:

1. 2007 - date
2. 2008 - date
3. 2007 - 2010
4. 2008 - date

What does " **... - date**" mean?

Comment: It follows no convention that I'm aware of, but she could have been using `date` to mean `present`. As in from 2007 to the current date.

Comment: It implies "till date". 2007- till date (as of today)

Comment: Or someone may forget to replace *"date"* by the current or appropriate date (if you need to do some research and place a *date* in the sentence to remember to do it later).

Comment: @Mysti No, it means "to date", though I think it's poor typesetting to let the dash stand for the word "to", since "to date" is an indivisible, idiomatic phrase.

Comment: @DavidRicherby, Yes, you are right. But I have been through a lot of resumes using a format such as 2007- till date.

Comment: It's probably more of a stylistic choice. Both "date" and the years have 4 characters, and using dashes/hyphens for both is consistent, even if it isn't 100% correct.

Comment: Maybe this person was simply too lazy to fill out all of the fields in their word processor's résumé template.

Answer (score 36):

There is an expression in English, ***[to date](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/to+date)***, which means *until now* or *up to the present time*.

This person has written that expression, in a sense, because the dash represents the word "to". Verbally therefore, the line would read "***2007 to date***".

Likewise, '2007 - 2008' would be spoken as "***2007 to 2008***", etc.

> **To date:** until now: *To date, only half of those invited have responded.*

thefreedictionary.com

In Britain, it's not uncommon to see this written on résumés (or [CVs](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/CV), as we call them).

**EDIT:** Although, more often than not, it will be written "**2007 - Present.**" This was pointed out to me in the comments.

Comment: In America, at least in my experience, resumes typically use “Present” rather than “date” in this kind of thing: *2007—Present* for example.

Comment: In my experience in UK I would expect "to present" rather than "to date". I'm not heavily involved in recruitment though so see a limited number of CVs. In general usage though the definition of "To date" given never has a start date in my experience. Like in the example it is just "To date" rather than "From when I sent it out to Date[...]".

Comment: @Chris: It's actually relatively common to have "(year) to date" - here's [one example](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/History_of_rail_transport_in_Great_Britain_1995_to_date) but a web search easily turns up lots more :)

Answer (score 12):

I've never encountered that particular usage before - it looks a bit strange, but there's certainly a degree of "logic" to it.

Suppose you've listing past employment on a CV, for example. When reading such "columnar table" contents out loud, you'd say...

> *Programmer, 1990 **to** 2000*
>    *Team Leader, 2000 **to** 2010*
>    *Chief Executive, 2010 **to date***

...where the written format might look something like this...

> *Programmer, 1990 - 2000*
>    *Team Leader, 2000 - 2010*
>    *Chief Executive, 2010 - date*

It's possible you might even be filling in boxes on a form where the dashes were already pre-printed. Since the first two dashes would definitely be read out as ***to***, it's not completely ridiculous to imply that the third one could be treated the same way, so given [***to date***](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/british/to-date) is a standard idiomatic usage meaning *up to the present time*, you could save yourself writing those extra two letters by letting the dash "stand for" the missing word.

I'm thus tempted to see it as a creative, but non-standard "double-duty" usage. (Akin to my habit of using a closing bracket as part of a smiley on ELU! :)

Comment: To me, using the dash to stand for "to" is poor typesetting in this case: "to date" is an indivisible, idiomatic phrase.  But, style issues aside, I agree that this is clearly what is meant.

Comment: @David: Well, it's a matter of opinion whether you see it as ignorant, creative, or whatever. (But since the "indivisible" argument applies in exactly the same way to the two characters in my smileys, I thought it was a good parallel! :)

Comment: Is this common on a CV/résumé in British English? In AmE I've only ever heard or seen "to present" (or with the dash, "—present").

Comment: I think this answer might benefit from adding an example to show what it would look like to mix dashes and "to", by writing "1990 - 2000" as is, while preserving "to date" as an "indivisible, idiomatic phrase", as suggested by @DavidRicherby.

Comment: @DavidRicherby: You might not like it, but [it's](http://www.inquest.org.uk/statistics/deaths-in-prison) [pretty](http://www.gbps.org.uk/information/rates/inland/special-delivery-next-day.php) [standard](http://www.amazon.co.uk/African-Appellate-Division-Reports-1910-date/dp/0620189797), even in [the](http://www.apmex.com/category/51120/silver-proof-sets-1992-date) [US](http://boards.collectors-society.com/ubbthreads.php?ubb=showflat&Number=8540964).

Comment: @Kevin - I can't say I've read a *lot* of CVs, but I wouldn't say it was common in British English. I have to agree with DavidRicherby - although it is completely obvious to me that it means "to date", I have never seen "- date" and I hence think it is a poor stylistic choice. I'd suggest "to date", "to present" and "- present" are all common stylistic choices; or even "- " with a gap meaning there is no end date.

Comment: @AndyT: I find it hard to believe anyone would actually fret about grammaticality/good style with "box-filling" entries like this. Personally, I'd be quite capable of putting a dash/strike-through on the final "end date" column in such a list/table (if I didn't just leave it blank). The issue is simply *Why would anyone write just **date**?*, to which the answer is *Because the tabular context leads them to interpret the preceding dash as **to***.

Answer (score 3):

A version of "to date"

TheFreeDictionary:

> to date
>
> Until now: To date, only half of those invited have responded.

Answer (score 1):

'Date' is used in this context to mean 'to now / to present'